# What's this loanword phenomenon called?

Tags: terminology, language-change, borrowing

I've noticed that loanwords often take on more specific meanings in the target language than in the source language. To give two very common examples, *sake* just means alcohol in Japanese and *salsa* just means sauce in Spanish, but those words refer to very specific types of alcohol and sauce in English.

What's this called and is there any research / recommended reading on this type of scope change for loanwords?

Comment: Sake isn't the best example - AFAIK "sake" used to refer to sake in Japanese, not just alcoholic beverages in general. Nihon-shu is a relatively new word. http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/was-sake-always-called-nihonshu

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's mostly commonly called *semantic restriction*, but *semantic narrowing* and *semantic specialization* are also in widespread use in the linguistic literature.

Comment: Do you mind adding a reference just for completeness? I mean, some book that treats about the subject would be perfect. But a whole book isn't necessary, even a single chapter that talks about it is acceptable. :)

Comment: This is a basic concept in semantics - you could use any undergraduate semantics text book, or even possibly the semantics chapter of a generalist text book. It depends on the model you're working in. I'm pretty sure such definitions are in The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics By Peter Hugoe Matthews.

Comment: Here is an article on the topic from About.com (I don't know if it's any good or not) [semantic narrowing](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/semnarrterm.htm)

Comment: My favorite English examples of semantic narrowing (specialization) are: girl (young person=>young female person), meat (food=>flesh food), wife (woman=>spouse), and deer (animal=>cervine animal). I remember reading some interesting works by Stephen Ullmann on this when I was in college.

Comment: Also, Traugott and Dasher (2001) http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511486500 is a good recent reference on semantic change. They mention Horn's 1984 classification of narrowing into two types, Q- and R-based narrowing (cf. rectangle vs. undertaker).

Comment: But neither this answer nor any of the comments deals specifically with loanwords. I believe there are two particular processes here: 1) the word is adopted with a particular cultural item and remains restricted to that item; and 2) the word is in competition with a native term for the more general sense, so there is no reason for it to spread its meaning wider.

Comment: jcm's answer is correct, and the same holds true for other languages; in German this process is common with English loanwords, e.g. the usage of the noun 'deal' in German will be understood with reference to finance (or drug dealing) rather than to any kind of deal. The German term for this is Bedeutungsverengung, i.e. semantic narrowing.